# Find a element with particular name attribute or id in HTML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a table with couple of columns, one of which is a link, on clicking it, I am calling JQuery click event. On click I want to get the value of a another column, which is a sibling of this column(td). how can i get it.

```
HTML
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th>RID</th>
                                            <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                            <th>Outlet Name</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Balance</th>
                                            <th>Stock</th>
                                            <th>Password</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td data-name="rid">5111879</td>
                                            <td data-name="mobile">9066587654</td>
                                            <td data-name="outlet">Rachels</td>
                                            <td>Indhiranagar, BL</td>
                                            <td>rach@yahoo.com</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>378665</td>
                                            <td><a href="#" id="retailer_stock">TRANSFER</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" id="retailer_reset">RESET</a></td>
                                        </tr>                                                                                                                           
                                    </table>
```

on clicking the id=retailer_stock, a modal pops up and should have the value of data-name='rid'. How should i do it.

```
Javascript
 $('#retailer_stock').click( function(event){
                    console.log($(this));
                    console.log($(event.target).closest('tr').children("[id = 'rid']"));
                    console.log($(this).closest('tr').children("[id = 'rid']"));
                    console.log($(event.target).closest('tr').find("[id = 'rid']"));
                    console.log($(event.target).siblings("[id = 'rid']"));
                    console.log($(this).closest("[id = 'rid']"));
                })
```

of these code lines, last two is not working, its not fetching me a result, can any of you explain why?

-thanks

Comment: Hi means ,, you can get on click id=retailer_stock to get value data-name='rid' as like on click get value "5111879".. Am i Right ?

Comment: just for curiosity, can't you put id to rid field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#retailer_stock').click( function(e){
    alert( $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text() )
})
```

Check demo: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/p70zfqpz/)

If you want to access that cell through `data-name` attribute use:

```
$('#retailer_stock').click( function(e){
    alert( $(this).closest('tr').find('[data-name="rid"]').text() )
})
```

However if you plan to have many rows in the table, you will end up with many elements with same `retailer_stock` id. To avoid this you may decide to change `id="retailer_stock"` to `class="retailer_stock"` and then change selector to  `$('.retailer_stock')`.

Comment: the first one is working, but the second one is not, i thing find() is not working

Comment: Please make sure you use the correct syntax. [In this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/p70zfqpz/) both methods work showing two consecutive alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Click event from jQuery:

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Capture the click on "retailer_stock" then you can retrieve the HTML from "rid"

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#retailer_stock').click(function (e) {
            alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-name="rid"]').text())
        })

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th>RID</th>
                                            <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                            <th>Outlet Name</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Balance</th>
                                            <th>Stock</th>
                                            <th>Password</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td data-name="rid">5111879</td>
                                            <td data-name="mobile">9066587654</td>
                                            <td data-name="outlet">Rachels</td>
                                            <td>Indhiranagar, BL</td>
                                            <td>rach@yahoo.com</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>378665</td>
                                            <td><a href="#" id="retailer_stock">TRANSFER</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" id="retailer_reset">RESET</a></td>
                                        </tr>                                                                                                                           
                                    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: R u sure? Here I get dat value

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()  please try     this

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#retailer_stock').click(function(e){
 $(this).parent().find('[data-name="rid"]').text()

});
```